# How can I downgrade a linux raid0 setup to use a simple partition

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid

I set up my desktop machine to use software raid 0 in ubuntu when I first set it up. Because it turns out that recovery from upgrading ubuntu (which always breaks things) is harder with /dev/md0 than /dev/sda1 I was thinking of trying to undo it. Is there any way to make a raid0 member partition an ext3 partition without copying everything over and redoing grub and initrd and all that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the data in a [RAID 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_0) is striped across all the disks, there is basically no easy way to convert any of the disks to any other filesystem. End of story.

---

That being said, there *might* be a way, if your RAID array has enough free space **and** you are using partitions for the array, not the whole disk (i.e. `/dev/sda1`, not `/dev/sda`).

You may be able to first shrink the array creating plain ext3 filesystems at the end of the disks **if** you have more than half of the array free. After you get rid of RAID 0, you still have to copy the data a couple of times around to get full-sized ext3 partitions on the disks.

So, to follow the completely untested idea:

- boot into rescue system (e.g. Ubuntu Live CD works fine)
- activate needed modules

  `modprobe md multipath raid0` (something else ..?)
- activate RAID array

  `cp /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf.backup`
  `mdadm --examine --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
  `mdadm -A --scan`
- check the fs

  `e2fsck -f /dev/md0`
- shrink the fs

  `resize2fs /dev/md0 30G` [leaving enough room based on existing disk usage, here <30G!])
- shrink the RAID array

  `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=36700160` (size in KiB: 35 * 1024^2 [leave room here, too!])
- grow the fs to max size avail

  `resize2fs /dev/md0`
- run fs check again (to be sure)

  `e2fsck -f /dev/md0`

Now you have RAID 0 in the beginning of the disks and free space at the end. Here, you might need to use `fdisk` to shrink the RAID partition and create new partitions for ext3.

Then you can

- make normal fs in the free disk space

  `mke2fs ...` (however you want)
- copy data from RAID to ext3

  `cp ...`
- remove RAID array

  `sudo umount /dev/md0`
  `sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md0` (stop array)
  `sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdx /dev/sdy ...` (clear superblocks of *each drive in array!*)
  `sudo mdadm --remove /dev/md0` (remove array)
- make ext3 to the beginning of one of the drives

  `mke2fs ...`
- copy data off from one of the disks
- make one partition to the disk, make ext3 fs on it
- copy data back to the full-disk fs
- repeat for all remaining disks (fiddling the data around until no data remains on the half RAID-half ext3 drives)

Note, that I haven't tested this procedure and you should take a full backup of your data! (As always when performing exessive disk operations.) Also, operations with `fdisk` typically require a reboot, so you have to keep carefully track of your system's state at all times.

All in all, I think it's *far* easier just to make a fresh install to ext3 and copy the data from RAID 0.

Comment: As it turned out I went with option B ("All in all").

Comment: I blew away one of the raid0 disks, installed a new fs on it new ubuntu install, then managed to get the old md0 up in broken mode (1 of 2 drives available) and mount it and copied everything off the old md0 to the new /sda1. I was hoping there might be some magic convert one of the raid0 partitions to a regular ext3 partition but I guess not. Well, it's done. Thanks.